Issue with imocx32.ocx register in window 11
I have vb6.0 windows application. i am running the application by clicking exe.
if we click one of the button in the application, i get the below error.
Run-time error '339': Component 'Imocx32.ocx' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid
This Imocx32.ocx is already available in system32 and SysWOW64 folder under windows.
i try to register this ocx by use run as admin mode, i get the below error.
The module "C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\Imocx32.ocx" failed to load.
Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
The specified module could not be found.
please help on this issue.
thanks
trying to register the OCX file in command prompt with run as administrator

If the OCX itself is present, the key part of the error message might be or one of its dependencies .  What else does this component rely on?

Does this OCX have an installer?  If so, you should use that installer instead of manually copying and registering the file.  You can also use a tool like Dependency Walker to see what might be missing.
